# docker volume not found for configuration option

Tags: docker

I am trying to run this docker command

```
docker run --rm --name lighthouse -it \
  -v $PWD/test-results/lighthouse:/home/chrome/reports \
  -v $PWD/lighthouse:/lighthouse \
  --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN femtopixel/google-lighthouse \
  --config-path=/lighthouse/config/custom-config.js \
  $full_url \
  --output html \
  --output json
```

But it is not picking up the `--config-path` argument, somehow I have the volume mapped wrong.

I am trying to create a volume called `lighthouse` but I get this error:

> /usr/bin/entrypoint: 11: exec:
>   --config-path=/lighthouse/config/custom-config.js: not found

Comment: you sholud put `.` before `/ligghthouse`  `--config-path=./lighthouse/config/custom-config.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending the url as the first parameter I think

```sh
docker run --rm --name lighthouse -it \
  -v $PWD/test-results/lighthouse:/home/chrome/reports \
  -v $PWD/lighthouse:/lighthouse \
  --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN femtopixel/google-lighthouse \
  $full_url \
  --config-path=/lighthouse/config/custom-config.js \
  --output html \
  --output json
```